# How to modify history browser list with query so that functions will be called

Tags: jquery, browser-history, pushstate

Do you know if there's a way in jquery to write in the history list of a browser a string to call a query function? For instance: in my page I animate the opening and closing of a div and when I click the back/forward button I want to fire the JS that open/close the div.

As far as I've read this syntax is correct

```
 history.pushState({id: 'SOME ID'}, '', 'myurl.html');
```

but if I write the following it won't work

```
 history.pushState({}, '', myjs());
```

UPDATE: Is it possibile to leave the ID space blank? I guess "ID" is the position in which you want to insert the string in the history state right?

UPDATE2: No one can help?

Answer (score 0):

It could be the syntax error you have near the end:

```
history.pushState({}, '', myjs(););
```

Should be:

```
history.pushState({}, '', myjs());
```

Comment: Thanks but that's my mistake writing here the post. That's not the fix.

Comment: That's a simple command to call the function to open or close the DIV. It could be anything. The main thing for me is to understand the correct syntax to insert the launch command (so the function) into the history state list.